# Google maps python API error on calling nearby_places function

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am geting an API error following error while trying to call places_nearby function in the python api for google maps 
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/places.py

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = maps_api_key)

places_result=gmaps.places_nearby(location=(40.714224, -73.961452))

Maybe I am calling it the wrong way. Could anyone please show the proper way to do it. Or Something else I need to fix
The image of the error is attatched below:
[Api Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0BV3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see in your screenshot you are getting the `INVALID_REQUEST` status code.

According to the Places API documentation:

> **INVALID_REQUEST** generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchStatusCodes

Indeed, in your code you specify the location parameter, but you don't provide a radius parameter. You can omit a radius parameter only if you specify `rankby=distance` in your request.

Have a look at **[nearby search documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests)**, it reads:

> **radius** — Defines the distance (in meters) within which to return place results. The maximum allowed radius is 50 000 meters. Note that radius must not be included if rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified.

I hope this helps!